# Problems sets for instruction

Tags: secondary-education, homework, primary-education, common-core

What resources are available for any grade level K- 12 that are aligned with the Common Core Mathematics Standards and Mathematical Practices that have sets of problems or problem banks that can be used by teachers for instruction or homework?

Comment: So you're looking for problem banks with official endorsements?

Comment: Yes, official endorsements would be wonderful or endorsements from educators that have actually used them.  Free resources would be best but excellent sources of any kind appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Can we include rich math tasks in our answers? If so, look at:

- http://visualpatterns.org
- http://graphingstories.com
- http://map.mathshell.org
- http://www.illustrativemathematics.org/
- http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com
- http://www.estimation180.com/
- http://www.dailydesmos.com/
- http://betterassessments.wordpress.com/
- http://maththinking.org/
- http://www.collaborativemathematics.org/

Comment: Absolutely!  Thank you.

Comment: +1 lots of good stuff here.

Answer (score 4):

The CME Project! It's a full four-year high school curriculum.

http://cmeproject.edc.org/

Comment: +1. I love CME. For curricular resources focused on developing mathematical habits of mind (though they mostly predated the publication of the Common Core), also see: CPM - http://www.cpm.org/ and Connected Math - http://connectedmath.msu.edu/ and IMP - http://mathimp.org/ and Math in the City's Contexts for Learning - http://www.contextsforlearning.com/seriesOverview.asp

Answer (score 2):

David Wees already mentioned in but I'd like to highlight [Illustrative Mathematics](http://www.illustrativemathematics.org/) - it's designed precisely for this purpose. (It's the brainchild of Bill McCallum, one of the lead authors of the Common Core math standards.)

Answer (score 1):

The Khan Academy has been developing a [common core map](https://www.khanacademy.org/commoncore/map). They have been working with Smarter Balanced and Illustrative Mathematics on the project.