# Looking for good Algebra I tasks

Tags: algebra

I don't use a textbook for my Algebra I class and am always spending hours looking for good math tasks for this course. Does anyone know of any printed materials that I can access where I can get ahold of good math "application" problems. I already use teacherspayteachers.com but even they do not have many good "word problems".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question! Welcome to the site. By the way, what topics do you cover in this course? Some of the best answerers on here are from other countries where the curriculum may be slightly different.

Comment: Why do you need "application" problems?

Comment: Look around for "mathemathics olympiad," both preparation material and the contest problems themselves. Typically very hard, but almost always interesting (and can be simplified, give a fat clue, or could point you in the right direction to come up with your own),

Comment: What is your reason for not using a textbook? (Knowing that may help me answer your question in more useful ways.)

Comment: Could you add some additional information of what Algebra I covers? This is something that can vary hugely from place to place (for example, the only course I am familiar with that bears that name is an introduction to group theory).

Comment: It would be helpful to specify what is meant by "Algebra I" and whether you mean "Algebra I" in the university, high school, middle school, or what. Not all of us teach in the US.

Answer (score 5):

Check out:

- [visualpatterns.org](http://www.visualpatterns.org/) - a great way to get them creating algebraic
  expressions to describe how something is growing
- [estimation180.com](http://www.estimation180.com/) - though estimation isn't a part of algebra,
  this will strengthen their number sense

  Also, there are lots of wonderful blogs by high school teachers. One way to use these to search for specific content is through the "virtual filing cabinets" a number of bloggers have created. [Sam Shah's](http://samjshah.com/worksheets-projects/) refers to others, so it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is acceptable question-answering etiquette, but [this list of rich math tasks](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/825/problems-sets-for-instruction/830#830) from another question is an excellent starting place.

(Aside: Is it better to link to the other list, or to copy and paste it into this question?)

Answer (score 1):

Tons of good stuff [here](http://algebra.mrmeyer.com/). ([Dan Meyer](http://blog.mrmeyer.com/)'s algebra I curriculum materials.)

Also, I heartily second Sue VanHattum's recommendation to check out Sam Shah's catalogue of math teacher bloggers' virtual filing cabinets.